# play framework tags: foreach passed argument

Tags: playframework

I have an applet tag which I'm using like this:

```
#{applet steps: 250, "world": "tutorials/level1.world", "req_onetime": "red_ant,5,8&red_ant,6,6&red_ant,5,4&red_ant,3,4&red_ant,2,6&red_ant,3,8"}
```

and the applet.html file is apart from html etc:

```
<applet ...>
#{if _steps}<param name="steps" value="${_steps}">#{/if}
....
</applet>
```

Can I have something like:

```
foreach passed param write '<param name=$1 value=$2>'
```

I know this isnt that important because the server/applet api should be well defined anyway... but since there are 10-20 parameters I have to pass, a short foreach would be easier to read anyway :-)

Is this possible **without** writing a somewhat complicated FastTag?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I think their is no way to iterate over the passed parameters (at least no documented way), but you can use a map or a list.

```
Java:
Map<String, String> map = new HashedMap<String, String>;

Template:
#{list items:map.keySet(), as:'key' }
    <param name="${key}" value="${map.get(key)}">
#{/list}
```

I think the key-set looses the order you put your values, so if you need to keep your order take a list.

```
Java:
List<NameValuePair> pairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>;
pairList.add(new NameValuePair("steps", "250");

Template:
#{list items:pairList, as:'pair' }
    <param name="${pair.name}" value="${pair.value}">
#{/list}
```